# Converting HTML to MSWord-Readable format

Tags: html, pdf, ms-word, tinymce

I want to convert / transfer HTML Transitional Code into a "MS-Word readable"-format...pdf would also do the job.

The converter should be a standalone program which I can reach by console...

P.S.: The input is created by TinyMCE and after this stored in a OracleDB 
P.P.S.: It should be able to understand CSS for div-positioning 
P.P.P.S: It should be Open Source :)

Thank you :)

Comment: Right Click -> View Source. Select all and copy to MS Word.

Comment: Hmm thank you but what I'm searching for should be able to get integrated into a script so that this is done dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your are looking for something like [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).
Here is a guy who blogged about his integration of that tool. It can convert HTML to PDF and includes css: http://beebole.com/en/blog/general/convert-html-to-pdf-with-full-css-support-an-opensource-alternative-based-on-webkit/

Comment: This seems to be awesome! :) I'm going to have a look at it.

P. S.: Sorry for my late response. I've been busy.